# How to use yumdownloader to download specific version of a source rpm?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, package-management

by using folloing command:

```
yumdownloader --source 'package-name-without-version'
```

It will only download the *newest* source rpm of said software.

how do I download specified version of source rpm using yumdownloader?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using

```
yumdownloader --source <package>-<version>
```

For example,

```
yumdownloader --source httpd-2.4.6-89.el7.centos
```